# regex replace in bewteen a value and a character

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I'm trying to replace something from a `css` text value:

```
"padding-left:5px;"
```

I want to replace `5px` by another value.

I can't figure out what javascript `regex` to use to use in my replace function.

Comment: Is it only going to be in padding-left?

Comment: No, it could be an other property. But here we'll say that yes.

Comment: Is it for a permanent change? Or a change on the fly?

Comment: A change on the fly. It can be repeated in time with the new value updated.

Comment: Can you not just update the elements style like document.getElementById('elementToChange').style.paddingLeft = newPadding;

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not overriding the cssText.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86614/discussion-between-ajaypayne-and-hetana).

Comment: @Hetana See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjvf4ygo/5/). I'm not sure what's the exact requirement.

Comment: Hey Jonny, your solution was the right one! You can eventually put it as an answer and I can validate it :-)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just do replace the chars which exists next to `:` with the string you want.

```
string.replace(/:.*/, ":20px;");
```

or

```js
var s = "padding-left:5px;"
alert(s.replace(/:[^;]*;/, ":20px;"))
```

Comment: wouldn't this replace all values in the entire css file to "20px"?

Comment: If there is something else around padding-left (right or left), how should I do? Thanks.

Comment: So I would take my whole string and use the following regex? 
/padding-left:[^;]*;/
Thanks

Comment: Be careful for this bit of regex, because it will subsistute ALL characters coming after the colon (:) with 20px; even a thousand lines of CSS which were placed (somewhere) after the colon.

Comment: @klaar what are you talking? `.` won't match line breaks.

Comment: @AvinashRaj CSS does not require anyone to put a linebreak after a semicolon; thus your solution is not guaranteed safe. People put multiple assignments on the same line on purpose (to save vertical space, or whatever reason they can come up with) or by automation (minifying).

Comment: @klaar then the second answer would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you only want to replace a number, that is preceded by substring `padding-left:`

```
str = str.replace(/(padding-left\s*:\s*)[\d.,]+(?=\s*px)/gi, "$1 20");
```

- `\s` is a [short](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for *whitespace character* `[ \t\r\n\f]`
- `(?=\s*px)` the [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check if number followed by `px` with optional space

Replace with `$1 20` where `$1` contains, what's captured inside the first capture group. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjvf4ygo/5/)

Comment: As I said, if for example my cssText is: 
-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone; padding-left: 13.046875px; padding-right: 13.046875px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);

It won't match. Any idea?